# Bitmap to int[,] conversion and vice versa

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap, integer

Consider the following two routines.

```
    //Tested
    ///Working fine. 
    public static Bitmap ToBitmap(int [,] image)
    {
        int Width = image.GetLength(0);
        int Height = image.GetLength(1);
        int i, j;
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height),
                                 ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        unsafe
        {
            byte* address = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;

            for (i = 0; i < bitmapData.Height; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < bitmapData.Width; j++)
                {
                    // write the logic implementation here
                    address[0] = (byte)image[j, i];
                    address[1] = (byte)image[j, i];
                    address[2] = (byte)image[j, i];
                    address[3] = (byte)255;
                    //4 bytes per pixel
                    address += 4;
                }//end for j

                //4 bytes per pixel
                address += (bitmapData.Stride - (bitmapData.Width * 4));
            }//end for i
        }//end unsafe
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        return bitmap;// col;
    }

    //Tested
    ///Working fine. 
    public static int[,] ToInteger(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        int[,] array2D = new int[bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height];

        BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
                                                 ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                                 PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

        unsafe
        {
            byte* address = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;

            int paddingOffset = bitmapData.Stride - (bitmap.Width * 4);//4 bytes per pixel

            for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.Height; j++)
                {
                    byte[] temp = new byte[4];
                    temp[0] = address[0];
                    temp[1] = address[1];
                    temp[2] = address[2];
                    temp[3] = address[3];

                    array2D[j, i] = BitConverter.ToInt32(temp, 0);

                    //4-bytes per pixel
                    address += 4;//4-channels
                }
                address += paddingOffset;
            }
        }
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

        return array2D;
    }
```

These two routines work fine for 32bpp images. These routines only work when pixel format is set to `PixelFormat.Format32bpp`. If I use `PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed`, it generates an exception.

In order to avoid that exception (also, I couldn't achieve seamless conversion between `byte` and `int` because of address calculation problem), I need to convert that 32 bit `Bitmap` to gray-scale every time the `int[,]` is converted back to a `Bitmap`. I want to get rid of this problem.

```
        Bitmap grayscale = Grayscale.ToGrayscale(InputImage);

        //Here, the Bitmap is treated as a 32bit image
        //to avoid the exception eventhough it is already
        //an 8bpp grayscale image.
        int[,] i1 = ImageDataConverter.ToInteger(grayscale);

        Complex[,] comp = ImageDataConverter.ToComplex(i1);

        int[,] i2 = ImageDataConverter.ToInteger(comp);

        Bitmap b2 = ImageDataConverter.ToBitmap(i2);

        //It is already a Grayscale image.
        //But, the problem is, b2.PixelFormat is set to 
        //PixelFormat.Formap32bpp because of those routines.
        //Hence the unnecessay conversion.
        b2 = Grayscale.ToGrayscale(b2);
```

I need to modify them to operate on 8bpp indexed (grayscale) images only.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What operation do you want? Do you mean you want to be able to pass in a `byte[,]` instead of `int[,]`? If not, then how is the `int[,]` to be interpreted? Will each 32 bit value just store a value between 0 and 255? Are they actually indexed as you write? If so, what palette should be used? Or are they really grayscale (as you also wrote)? Will there be four pixels packed into each 32 bit value? Either way, how are the 8 bit values to be interpreted? Do you want to output a 32bpp image, or should the output also be 8bpp? You have left out pretty much every important part of the specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int[,] ToInteger(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    int[,] array2D = new int[bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height];

    BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
                                            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                            PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    int bytesPerPixel = sizeof(byte);

    unsafe
    {
        byte* address = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;

        int paddingOffset = bitmapData.Stride - (bitmap.Width * bytesPerPixel);

        for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.Height; j++)
            {
                byte[] temp = new byte[bytesPerPixel];

                for (int k = 0; k < bytesPerPixel; k++)
                {
                    temp[k] = address[k];
                }

                int iii = 0;

                if (bytesPerPixel >= sizeof(int))
                {
                    iii = BitConverter.ToInt32(temp, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    iii = (int)temp[0];
                }

                array2D[j, i] = iii;

                address += bytesPerPixel;
            }
            address += paddingOffset;
        }
    }
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

    return array2D;
}

public static Bitmap ToBitmap(int[,] image)
{
    int Width = image.GetLength(0);
    int Height = image.GetLength(1);
    int i, j;

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

    BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height),
                             ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

    int bytesPerPixel = sizeof(byte);

    unsafe
    {
        byte* address = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;

        for (i = 0; i < bitmapData.Height; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < bitmapData.Width; j++)
            {
                byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(image[j, i]);

                for (int k = 0; k < bytesPerPixel; k++)
                {
                    address[k] = bytes[k];
                }

                address += bytesPerPixel;
            }

            address += (bitmapData.Stride - (bitmapData.Width * bytesPerPixel));
        }
    }
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

    Grayscale.SetGrayscalePalette(bitmap);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would be nice

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deal with an indexed bitmap, you need to read each byte of the image, and lookup the color from the palette.  When you save the image, you'll need to do the reverse logic:

```
public static Bitmap ToBitmap(int[,] image)
{
    int width = image.GetLength(0);
    int height = image.GetLength(1);
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
                                ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    int stride = bitmapData.Stride;

    // A dictionary of colors to their index values
    Dictionary<int, int> palette = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    // A flat list of colors
    List<Color> paletteList = new List<Color>();

    unsafe
    {
        byte* address = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                // Get the color from the Bitmap
                int color = image[x, y];
                if (!palette.ContainsKey(color))
                {
                    // This color isn't in the palette, go ahead and add it
                    palette.Add(color, palette.Count);
                    paletteList.Add(Color.FromArgb(color));
                    if (palette.Count >= 256)
                    {
                        // The palette is too big.  Ideally this function would
                        // dither some pixels so it could handle this condition
                        // but that would make this example overly complicated
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Too many colors in image");
                    }
                }

                // And lookup the index of the color in the palette and
                // add it to the BitmapData's memory
                address[stride * y + x] = (byte)palette[color];
            }
        }
    }

    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

    // Each time you call Bitmap.Palette it actually returns
    // a Clone of the object, so we need to ask for a cloned
    // copy here.
    var newPalette = bitmap.Palette;

    // For each one of our colors, add it to the palette object
    for (int i = 0; i < paletteList.Count; i++)
    {
        newPalette.Entries[i] = paletteList[i];
    }

    // And since this is a clone, assign it back to the bitmap
    // so it'll take effect.
    bitmap.Palette = newPalette;

    return bitmap;
}

public static int[,] ToInteger(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    if (bitmap.Palette.Entries.Length == 0)
    {
        // This doesn't appear to have a palette, so this operation doesn't
        // make sense
        throw new InvalidOperationException("bitmap is not an indexed bitmap");
    }

    int width = bitmap.Width;
    int height = bitmap.Height;
    int[,] array2D = new int[width, height];

    BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
                                                ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                                                PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

    unsafe
    {
        // Pull out the stride to prevent asking for it many times
        int stride = bitmapData.Stride;
        byte* address = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                // Lookup the color based off the pixel, and set it's value
                // to the return array
                array2D[x, y] = bitmap.Palette.Entries[address[stride * y + x]].ToArgb();
            }
        }
    }

    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

    return array2D;
}
```

Comment: Very slow! Takes a long time to execute.

Comment: Yep.  I was trying to show the process and solution to your issue, not make the most performant solution possible.